# Find docs without sub collection

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to construct search query to find all docs that do not have any subcollections or do not have some specific subcollection?

E.g. in this example I want to get `doc3`:

```
doc1
    - collection1
doc2
    - collection2
doc3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with a single query on the top-level collection.

You'll need to either:

1. Read all docs from the top-level collection, loop over them, and then check for any documents (with a `limit(1)`) in the subcollection for that document.
2. Read all documents from all those subcollections with a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) and then check which documents from the top-level collection are missing.

I'd typically go with the first option, as it is less likely to lead to scalability issues.

Of course an even better solution is to keep the necessary information in the documents in the top-level collection, like with a `hasSubcollectionICareAbout` field or a `documentsInMySubcollection` count field for example. This means you have to do more work on writing the data, but it typically pays itself back very quickly in both the cost and code complexity of these reads.

Comment: I do like your best solution variant. I just thought maybe I missed something and I could find the docs in one query without any additional count information. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on @Frank's second idea: keep the parent doc updated with a count of children. Use a cloud function roughly like this:

```
export const wroteMySubcollection = 
  functions.firestore.document('collection/{id}/subcollection/{subId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {

  let increment = 0
  if (!change.before.exists) increment = 1;
  else if (!change.after.exists) increment = -1;

  return db.collection('collection').doc(id) // the parent
    .update({ subcollectionLength: FieldValue.increment(increment) });
});
```

Now the client can query like this:

```
db.collection('collection').where('subcollectionLength', '==', 0);
```